# How to repair chipped tile edges on an external facing corner?

Tags: tiling

I've got these problems in an apartment that has been rented out.

No tile trim was ever used and it shows!

[image: chipped external corner tiles]

[image: chipped external corner tiles]

What's the best way of repairing this short of replacing all the tiles? Can I put some metal trim on this to hide the damage and prevent further damage?

I'm guessing that they bevelled the edges in order to meet flush like that.

PS: just bought this aluminium trim and will try it. Just stick with silicone and tape it down until it's cured

[image]

Edit: Result looking good.  Tape is just temporary!

[image: trim in place]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah metal trim is probably the best way. if you're cheap there's aluminium angle that can be glued on using bathroom silicone caulk.

For a slightly better look get a strip of stainless-steel bent 95 degrees along the length (so the angle is 85 degrees). and glue that on in the same way.